# Конвертация списка дат и времени в формат cron (java)

Tags: java, spring, cron

Мучаюсь с поиском информации уже пол дня и совсем ничего найти не могу

На вход дается список с датой и временем
(Примеры:
Input:
"2022-01-25T08:00:00"
"2022-01-25T08:30:00"
)

- на выход надо получить их же в cron формате.
  (Output:
  "0 0/30 8-9 * * *" )

Подскажите пожалуйста как добиться этого результата

Comment: `"2022-01-25T08:00:00" "2022-01-27T08:10:00" "2022-01-28T06:22:12" "2022-01-29T18:31:07"` сможете вручную хотя бы перевести в крон? Чет мне кажется это довольно сложная задача. Вам оно зачем надо?

Comment: В ручную могу. Надо это так как дали такое задание и мне очень интересно понять как оно решается.